# GET returning only true params (Clojure)

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to return 'profile' that were created with :public-profile true.

This is my schema:

```
  (s/defschema profile
   {:id s/Int
   :name s/Str
   :last-name s/Str
   :age s/Int
   :origin {:country s/Str
        :city s/Str}
   :public-profile Boolean        
   })
```

And this is my GET:

```
    :get {
           :responses {http-status/ok {:schema [profile]}}
           :handler (fn [_] (ok (vals @profiles)))}}))
```

I'm kind of newbie programmer on Clojure and I would like to know how to make my get return only public-profile that were true. Just looking for a simple function to make it happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming @profiles is a map where values are profiles, then you can return only profiles where `:public-profile` is true with [filter](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter). For example:

```
(filter
  (fn [profile] (:public-profile profile))
  (vals @profiles))
```

In clojure keywords are actually functions and return the value corresponding to them when applied to maps, so a more concise (and I believe idiomatic) way of writing this would be:

```
(filter :public-profile (vals @profiles))
```

Comment: I tryied on that way:      

            :get {
               :responses {http-status/ok {:schema [profile]}}
               :handler (fn [profile] 
                          (filter :public-profile (ok (vals @profiles))))}}))
But now, it's returning "no content" on my GET, could u help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `ok` function is doing here but I think you want: `:get { :responses {http-status/ok {:schema [profile]}} :handler (fn [profile] (ok (filter :public-profile (vals @profiles))))}}))`

Comment: "ok" function is used in case of my POST returns a 201 code (created), they work togheter, if @profiles were found, my GET returns to me 200 code (ok). I've tryied this solution and it works! Thank you sooo, soo much!